# Index a list of GroovyRowResult into a Map

Tags: grails, groovy

Suppose I have a list of GroovyRowResult entries, as a result of an SQL query against a database:

```
def myQueryResults = [
    {COLUMN0 = 'VALUE0', COLUMN1 = 'COMMONVALUE0'}, 
    {COLUMN0 = 'VALUE1', COLUMN1 = 'COMMONVALUE0'}, 
    {COLUMN0 = 'VALUE2', COLUMN1 = 'COMMONVALUE0'}, 
    {COLUMN0 = 'VALUE3', COLUMN1 = 'COMMONVALUE1'}, 
    {COLUMN0 = 'VALUE4', COLUMN1 = 'COMMONVALUE1'}, 
    {COLUMN0 = 'VALUE5', COLUMN1 = 'COMMONVALUE1'}
]
```

I'd like to transform this list of entries into this map structure:

```
def result = {
    COMMONVALUE0 : ['VALUE0', 'VALUE1', 'VALUE2'],
    COMMONVALUE1 : ['VALUE3', 'VALUE4', 'VALUE5']
}
```

I know that in Java, this can be done with Guava, using `Maps::uniqueIndex`.

What is the Groovy way to accomplish this? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** OK I came up with this:

```
def rows = db.rows(myQuery)
def result = [:]
rows.each {
    if (!result[it.COLUMN1]) {
        result[it.COLUMN1] = []
    }
    result[it.COLUMN1] << it.COLUMN0
}
```

I'm sure there must be a Groovier way to do it right?

Comment: `def result=[:].withDefault{[]}` would save you the if in the `each`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupBy` does what you want.  then some collecting

```
myQueryResults.groupBy{ it.COLUMN1 }.collectEntries{[it.key, it.value.COLUMN0]}
```

Comment: or, `myQueryResults.groupBy{ it.COLUMN1 }{ it.COLUMN0 }.collectEntries {[it.key, it.value.keySet()]}`

Comment: the easiest way is to `println` yourself from left to right.  the groupBy uses the result of the closure to create map with the result as keys and the ingoing object added to a list for that key.  so we have a map with the value of COL1 and a list of all your entries.  collectEntries returns a map from [key,value] returned in the closure.  so we take here the key from the ingoing map and collect all COL0 values (it.value.COLUMN0 is short for it.value*.COLUMN0 (the spread operator) and returns a list of all results of the called method/property (in this case the key in the map))

Answer (score 1):

You can `collectEntries`:

```
def myQueryResults = [
    [COLUMN0 : 'VALUE0', COLUMN1 : 'COMMONVALUE0'], 
    [COLUMN0 : 'VALUE1', COLUMN1 : 'COMMONVALUE0'], 
    [COLUMN0 : 'VALUE2', COLUMN1 : 'COMMONVALUE0'], 
    [COLUMN0 : 'VALUE3', COLUMN1 : 'COMMONVALUE1'], 
    [COLUMN0 : 'VALUE4', COLUMN1 : 'COMMONVALUE1'], 
    [COLUMN0 : 'VALUE5', COLUMN1 : 'COMMONVALUE1']
]


groups = { maps ->
  maps.collectEntries { e -> 
    [ (e.COLUMN1) : maps.findAll { it.COLUMN1 == e.COLUMN1 }*.COLUMN0 ] 
  }
}


assert groups(myQueryResults) == [
    COMMONVALUE0 : ['VALUE0', 'VALUE1', 'VALUE2'],
    COMMONVALUE1 : ['VALUE3', 'VALUE4', 'VALUE5']
]
```