# Using groupBy in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a list of Users as

```
def items = [[name:"tony", age:4], [name:"tony", age: 5], [name:"alan", age:16]]
```

I want to group them by name so, but only want the age in list so I want

```
["tony": [4, 5], "alan": [16]]
```

When I do

```
def groups = items.groupBy {it.name}
```

I get:
    [tony:[[name:tony, age:4], [name:tony, age:5]], alan:[[name:alan, age:16]]]

So still a bit more work to do to get what I want.  Any tips?

Comment: Duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794341/index-a-list-of-groovyrowresult-into-a-map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
def items = [[name:"tony", age:4], [name:"tony", age: 5], [name:"alan", age:16]]
def t = items.groupBy { it.name }.collectEntries { [(it.key):(it.value*.age)] }
assert t == ['tony':[4,5],'alan':[16]]
```

Answer (score 5):

you can also do it in 1 loop instead of 2:

```
def items = [[name:"tony", age:4], [name:"tony", age: 5], [name:"alan", age:16]]
def groupped = items.inject( [:].withDefault{ [] } ){ res, curr ->
  res[ curr.name ] << curr.age
  res
}
```