# Group database records using ESB mule

Tags: groovy, mule, esb, mule-el, splitter

I have mule flow which selects few records from database tables which looks like below.

```
StudentID   Subject     Mark 
1           Maths        98  
2           Literature   62
1           Science      56  
1           Anatomy      63
3           Zoology      38
2           Algebra      63
```

Here i need to group the records based on studentID and need to send for further processing. Hence i have placed splitter component immediate after database node. But in MEL expression how can we group the records ?

Is there any other best way to do this ESB mule ?

Update - I need to split the message based on StudentID (group by). I found [groovy can do grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870210/using-groupby-in-groovy). But whether we can split the messages using groovy.

Comment: Can you please post your desired output

Comment: Are you able to use the **enterprise $$** datawave or just the community edition?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Java object and implement callable. Use this method to alter the payload. Then I would use a second database component and use the payload object (MEL) in the second query.

This object transforms data from a Database component output flow to a hybrid object that's used to display JSON with an embedded array of child data.

https://github.com/dlwhitehurst/modusbox-orders/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dlw/transport/OrdersTransformSingleton.java

Check out the return on the callable method and see how you can "transform" the data yourself.

Here's the snippet in the mule config that instances the needed Java component.

```
    <spring:beans>
  <spring:bean id="ordersTransform" name="OrdersTransformSingleton"
    class="org.dlw.transport.OrdersTransformSingleton" scope="singleton">
  </spring:bean>
  <spring:bean id="jdbcDataSource" class="org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <spring:property name="driverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <spring:property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
  </spring:bean>      
</spring:beans>
```

The object is used in the flow like this ...

```
    <flow name="get:/orders:api-config">
    <set-payload value="[&#xD;&#xA;  {&#xD;&#xA;    &quot;orderId&quot;: 1233,&#xD;&#xA;    &quot;placementDate&quot;: &quot;2016-06-02&quot;,&#xD;&#xA;    &quot;customerName&quot;: &quot;Sally Hansen&quot;,&#xD;&#xA;     &quot;orderItems&quot;:[&#xD;&#xA;       {&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;orderItemId&quot;: 1323,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;orderId&quot;: 438577,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;itemId&quot;: 23058,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;itemName&quot;: &quot;Salt&quot;,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;itemCount&quot;: 3,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;qtyItemCost&quot;: &quot;$2.76&quot;&#xD;&#xA;       },&#xD;&#xA;       {&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;orderItemId&quot;: 1323,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;orderId&quot;: 438577,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;itemId&quot;: 23058,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;itemName&quot;: &quot;Pepper&quot;,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;itemCount&quot;: 3,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;qtyItemCost&quot;: &quot;$8.79&quot;&#xD;&#xA;       }&#xD;&#xA;     ]  &#xD;&#xA;  },&#xD;&#xA;  {&#xD;&#xA;    &quot;orderId&quot;: 1233,&#xD;&#xA;    &quot;placementDate&quot;: &quot;2016-06-02&quot;,&#xD;&#xA;    &quot;customerName&quot;: &quot;Billy Wilson&quot;,&#xD;&#xA;     &quot;orderItems&quot;:[&#xD;&#xA;       {&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;orderItemId&quot;: 1323,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;orderId&quot;: 438577,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;itemId&quot;: 23058,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;itemName&quot;: &quot;Wheat Flour&quot;,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;itemCount&quot;: 3,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;qtyItemCost&quot;: &quot;$10.12&quot;&#xD;&#xA;       },&#xD;&#xA;       {&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;orderItemId&quot;: 1323,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;orderId&quot;: 438577,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;itemId&quot;: 23058,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;itemName&quot;: &quot;Tomato Paste&quot;,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;itemCount&quot;: 3,&#xD;&#xA;         &quot;qtyItemCost&quot;: &quot;$9.21&quot;&#xD;&#xA;       }&#xD;&#xA;     ]  &#xD;&#xA;  }&#xD;&#xA;]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT a.orderId, a.customerName, a.placementDate, b.orderItemId, b.itemId, c.itemName, b.itemCount, c.itemCost FROM modusbox.orders a, modusbox.orderitems b, modusbox.items c WHERE a.orderId = b.orderId AND b.itemId = c.itemId]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
    <component doc:name="Java">
        <spring-object bean="OrdersTransformSingleton" />
    </component>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better place dataweave component and use 'groupBy' logic.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#group-by

Comment: This example does not split the message based on the grouping. I need to split the message based on studentID. I apologies if my query is not more explanatory.. Can we have any groovy component immediate after database node to split messages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870210/using-groupby-in-groovy

Answer (score 0):

DataWeave is the right option for groupBy. If you don't have DataWeave as choice (using Community Edition), you can have a quick win with script engine groovy.

List which should be groupBy attribute `mail`

```
[
      {
        "mail": "smith@example.com",
        "name": "lastname",
        "value": "Smith"
      },
      {
        "mail": "smith@example.com",
        "name": "firstname",
        "value": "John"
      },
      {
        "mail": "doe@example.com",
        "name": "lastname",
        "value": "Doe"
      },
      {
        "mail": "doe@example.com",
        "name": "firstname",
        "value": "Lisa"
      }
]
```

Mule script component

```
<scripting:component>
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        <![CDATA[flowVars['recipients'].groupBy{it.mail}]]>
    </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

Result of groupBy `mail`

```
{
    "smith@example.com": [
        {
        "mail": "smith@example.com",
        "name": "lastname",
        "value": "Smith"
        },
        {
        "mail": "smith@example.com",
        "name": "firstname",
        "value": "John"
        }
    ],
    "doe@example.com": [
        {
        "mail": "doe@example.com",
        "name": "lastname",
        "value": "Doe"
        },
        {
        "mail": "doe@example.com",
        "name": "firstname",
        "value": "Lisa"
        }
    ]
}
```

Works fine with Mule 3.8.1 CE.